# 500 Internal Server Error trying to insert a record to AsterixDB

Tags: internal-server-error, asterixdb

I am trying to insert a json object into AsterixDB through python code. Im getting the data in the correct format but when I try to use sql to insert the record into the database it throws a 500 internal server error.

It connects to the database fine earlier in the python code and in a different python test file I can manually insert the exact same record just fine

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log file cc.log in the folder ../apache-asterixdb-0.9.8/opt/local/logs I realized my mistake. [cc.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB9Fo.jpg)

It says here [cc.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNpmz.png) that I was inserting duplicate records into asterixDB. My issue was I had my insert statement at the wrong place in my loop in my python code.